# Como apontar links para raiz do site sem usar o .htaccess

Tags: php, html, html5

Como faço para apontar o diretório raiz sem precisar que eu coloque o index.php nos links e sem utilizar o `.htaccess` ?

**Exemplo**:

```
<a href="index.php" class="nav-brand"><img src="logo.png" alt="Logo" /></a>
```

No exemplo acima, o logotipo que aparece em todas as páginas tem o link apontando para a página principal e eu queria apontar sem ter que chamar o index.php no link, tem alguma forma de fazer isso sem ter que utilizar o `.htaccess` ?

Comment: Já tentou usar o `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`?

Comment: @TaffarelXavier Não, mas essa variável global é dependente do Apache não é ? Ela não é tão recomendada para certas coisas, eu poderia usar ela no caso de apontamento de links ?

Comment: Segundo esta resposta, sim: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13394924/php-serverdocument-root

Comment: Machado, qual a fonte? Porque, segundo o site oficial, há comentários com expressivos votos com o uso dela: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.server.php#112425

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Traduzido [PHP $ _SERVER ['DOCUMENT_ROOT']](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13394924/php-serverdocument-root):**

Nesse tipo de cenário, é sempre melhor criar um arquivo `config.php` e salvá-lo no diretório raiz. No arquivo de configuração, você define alguns parâmetros.

Chame esse arquivo de configuração em todas as páginas. Seu arquivo de configuração pode ser semelhante ao abaixo.

```
define('APP_NAME','nome-do-projeto'); //dentro da pasta htdocs (xamp) ou da www (wamp)  
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://localhost/'); 
define('SITE_NAME', 'http://localhost/');   
define('DOCUMENT_ROOT',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].APP_NAME);
```

Você também pode definir seu diretório para imagens, css, etc. que você acha que serão usadas em vários lugares.

Então, você pode chamar desta forma:

```
<a href="<?php echo HTTP_SERVER.'index.php';?>" class="nav-brand"><img src="<?php echo HTTP_SERVER.'logo.png';?>" alt="Logo" /></a>
```

Comment: Como eu carrego depois esse arquivo de configuração nas páginas ?

Comment: Usa include ou require.

Comment: E qual o método ideal de incluir esse arquivo de configuração, usando `include`, `require`, `include_once` ou `require_once` ? E você pode me dar um exemplo de onde colocar isso ?

Comment: Há diferenças entre elas, mas, basicamente, todas fazem a mesma coisa. Tu podes usar include. Mas você pode dar uma olhada, aqui mesmo, a diferença entre elas.

Comment: Tu podes colocar sempre no topo dos arquivos `php` ou você pode usar um `autoload`.

Comment: Consegui colocando o include no topo chamando o arquivo php conforme você informou e deu certinho, muito obrigado!

Comment: Nos links fiz da seguinte forma: `<a href="<?php echo HTTP_SERVER.APP_NAME; ?>" class="nav-brand"><img src="<?php echo HTTP_SERVER.APP_NAME; ?>/logo.png" alt="Logo" /></a>`. Como estou utilizando o EasyPHP para desenvolver um projeto, ele está sendo reproduzido a partir do Pendrive, então no painel eu criei um projeto para poder rodar diretamente do Pendrive e não da raiz.